# Does API availability work differently in switch versus if?

Tags: swift, healthkit, availability

I'm working with new [asleep values from HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategoryvaluesleepanalysis/asleeprem) which are available since iOS 16. My app supports iOS 15+. Is there any reason why `if` statements with `==` need an API availability check while `switch`/`case` statements do not? Is it safe to use it in a `switch` statement without availability check?

```
guard let value = HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis(rawValue: sample.value) else { return nil }
if value == .asleepREM { // 'asleepREM' is only available in iOS 16.0 or newer
}

if case asleepREM = value { // no error
}

switch value { // no error
case .asleepREM:
    break 
default:
    break
}
```

[image]

Comment: The issue isn’t the switch the issue is that the specific case is only available in iOS 16

Comment: @loremipsum yes, it is only available since iOS 16, thats the whole point. The question is, why API availability check is not required in switch statement or in if case.